# Trajectory of a rock

Tags: algebra-precalculus

During the eruption of Mount St. Helens in 1980, debris was ejected at a speed of over $440$ feet per second ($300$ miles per hour). The height in feet of a rock ejected at angle of $75^
\circ$ is given by the equation $y(t)=-16t^2+425t+8200$, where $t$ is the time in seconds after the eruption. The rock's horizontal distance in feet from the point of ejection is given by $x(t)=113t$. Assuming the elevation of the surounding countryside is $0$ feet, what is the horizontal distance from the point of ejection to the point where the rock would have landed? Round your answer to the nearest foot.

---

I have no idea in understanding this problem, can I get a hint please?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Where will the rock be (vertically) once it lands? How long does it take for it that to happen? How far does it go horizontally in that time?

Comment: Do I have to find the time at which the rock lands? Do I set $y(t)=0$?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you need to do.

Comment: Yes. Set y=0, then how many answers will you get?

Comment: I got $t=39.528$ seconds. The other solution was negative so I omitted it.